# Using Camera for Video Record in Background with UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

My app start a video recording automatically at load if any "video capture - supported" device is detected. I can get preview from the camera while recording is continued also.

However, if I minimize the app, cameras goes offline. I can run the other processes with using deferral object in EnteringBackground event, only cameras goes offline.

How can I use the cameras and continuing the video record in background ?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to capture video in the background.

Comment: Hmm, If can I disable the minimize in my app, it will suspended and terminated only when user closed it. So, the camera will run without paused if app don't closed. Can I do a workaround like this ?

Comment: As far as I know, it is also not a possible scenario.